# Connecting to a remote computer - desktop

Tags: php, javascript, remote-access

I want to be able to connect (from a server) to a remote PC and be able to access it's files. I am trying to do this with PHP or JavaScript.

So I am wondering if 1) it's possible and 2) how to do it.

Does anyone have any examples/solutions?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about what you want to achieve? Are you in a network? Are you talking about users browsing to your site, and you connecting to their files?

Answer (score 2):

On the client side, you won't be able to manipulate the filesystem at will **unless** you have some help of an extension of some sort (e.g. NPAPI based).

Futhermore, you mention **from server to client**: I hope you are not implying starting a connection on the server side to a client browser because in this case this is clearly not possible.

Of course, if you are talking **outside of the browser environment** (e.g. using Javascript (Rhino)) on a Desktop application, then this changes the situation (and capabilities).

Comment: What I am trying to achieve: I am trying to scope out a "File Backup" application where users can schedule to have their files backed up from their computer on our servers.

When it comes time to perform the backup, our server needs to connect to their PC and then upload the files. It doesn't necessarily have to be through a browser but the whole idea to be be able to connect to their PC.

I really don't think this is possible but I have come across another application which does "Remote Backup". I tend to think that it should be the other way around: The remote PC connecting with our server..

Comment: The Client PC connecting to the Remote Server is a much more plausible operational scenario indeed.

Comment: Now in terms of building a Desktop application that can meet those requirements, you could of course choose either JS or PHP but I am unclear if either of those would be appropriate. Ever thought of Python?

Answer (score 0):

Well this is not easy to accomplish which is why FTP seems the reasonable approach. Especially, dealing with large files. The connection though will have to be initiated from the client side.